# Dart2 Grammar not recognizing Collection literals

Tags: parsing, antlr4, grammar, literals, dart-2

i'm using a grammar from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/dart2/Dart2.g4, and trying to recognize Collection literals, tehre is an example of a sample in https://dart.dev/#try-dart, but the grammar does not recognize "var", and in this case literals like dict sets and even lists, maybe its not recognized in antlr4 because its not defined to do so, but would like to have help find what is the root of the problem, maybe i'm doing something wrong....

Comment: You don't provide your input. For sake of argument, I'll assume it is the code sample at https://dart.dev/samples#variables. From the grammar, 'var' variable declarations should be in a `block`, e.g., a function body. When I copy and paste the example into the online "Try Dart in your browser", it gives an error. If that snippet is copied into the block of "Hello world", it works fine, and Antlr parses it. In other words, these are incomplete examples.

Comment: Yes, if you try  https://dart.dev/#try-dart, go to Collection literals and copy the example and try to parse it, it will not recognize var as lists, sets and dictionary's, but if you try const instead of var it works so i assume the Grammar is incomplete, but you can try and give me your opinion.

Comment: Yep, the grammar doesn't parse several examples. The current spec is 2.2 July 29, 2019. The Dart2.g4 grammar is dated April 2019 (actually 21 May). I can't find the .pdfs for a previous version of the language spec in the github repository but haven't checked the repo much, Wayback, or regenerating an older version from Tex. The .g4 grammar doesn't have a version number, so who knows what version it's trying to support. It needs to have the version, date, location of the spec. Sloppy.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will try to add that new features so it can parse new things like the literals i mentioned above, and maybe merge with the old grammar to improve it

Comment: There are actually multiple errors in the grammar because it's slightly out of date. But beware: the spec is wrong. I have an updated grammar and some explicit tests [here](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/Dart2). It's not complete, but it is better. Unfortunately, the writers of the spec do not actually scrape the spec from the [implementation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/pkg/_fe_analyzer_shared/lib/src/parser/parser_impl.dart), so that is one reason why it is wrong.

Comment: For example, `functionExpressions` do not end with a ';'--no expression ends in a semi-colon! EOF must be on the `compilationUnit` not a sub-rule so that Antlr will consume all the input. The rules for `setLiteral`, `setOrMapLiteral` are missing. A top-level declaration can be a `variableDeclaration`, but also an `initializedVariableDeclaration`.

Comment: Going to check the grammar you have on your github and do some tests, thank you very much for the help, as i update and find new missing i will update you so you can improve your grammar, but your comments were very helpful in this matter

Comment: I'm doing a master thesis in this area and using Dart2 as the main language to parse, so i need the best grammar possible, so i can evaluate some dart2 programs and test it in the grammar, so i need to cover every case possible

Comment: I've started writing a tool [here](https://github.com/kaby76/ScrapeDartSpec) that scrapes the CFG rules from the Dart2 spec that is written in Latex. It is not completely functional, but using it, I have found some errors in an updated grammar that I hand-entered--even which I painstakingly checked. It has also found several typos in the Dart2 spec itself. It is a disgrace that people type in via hand grammars from specs, or with hubris write an implementation, and not use tools to extract the grammar, find problems and optimize.

Comment: Going to check the tool seems very interesting. Its a shame indeed, but i guess most of the people do that...

Comment: For an up-to-date grammar, check out https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/tools/spec_parser/Dart.g. This is written by Dart's Erik Ernst, but it is not scraped from spec. There are errors in the spec too, but I am letting Dart know. [Grammars-g4/dart2/Dart2.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/dart2/Dart2.g4) is old and has errors, e.g., commas instead of periods in a couple of places https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/dart2/Dart2.g4#L835. So, it's best not to use at this point.

Comment: Going to check the grammar from Erik Ernst, looks like its more organized, and if i used Dar2.g4 looks like i would take more time trying to correct errors than doing anything productive... Thanks again, you are being very helpful in this matter :)